# Run snap VLC as root user

Tags: root, vlc, snap

Installed VLC through snap. Installed version is 3.0. I tried to change getuid / geteuid to getppid in /snap/bin/vlc-wrapper but could edit the file. So, how to run vlc installed through snap as root user in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Why do you want to run vlc as root?

Comment: Running VLC or other user-space programs is a wrong fix to (almost) all problems.

Comment: It's my personal computer. I do a lot of installs and removes for testing softwares. So, most of the time I am logged in as root. And sometime I feel like watching videos without logging out and logging in again as normal user. So, want to run vlc as root.

Comment: correction - "but could edit the file" will be "but could not edit the file"